# Skinnable audio player (or something similar to Windows Vista audio control in task bar) - for the web

Tags: asp.net, html, flash, audio

Anyone know of a skinnable audio player (or something similar to Windows Vista audio control in task bar) that i can embed in my website?

- A player that can be customized to
  use a 'speaker' icon instead of a
  'play' icon.  When the speaker is
  clicked, the volume can be adjusted
  or turned off.
- The option of being able to autoplay
  and set the default volume level.

Comment: I'm guessing you want something that you can embed into your own website?

Answer (score 0):

dunno if this is any use to you - http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/

Comment: close.  I edited the original question to be more specific on what I'm trying to find.